# How to run an executable that contains a space in path from command line on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, cmd, space

```
H:\>"H:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0beta\bin\R.exe"
'H:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

H:\>"H:\Progra~1\R\R-3.4.0beta\bin\R.exe"
The system cannot find the path specified.

H:\>H:\Progra~1\R\R-3.4.0beta\bin\R.exe
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I tried using `"`...`"` and `Progra~1` and both are not working on Windows 10.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: " " should work. You should get something like `'"H:\Program Files\R...."' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` I am suspecting you typed wrong double quotes.

Comment: First one it did not even recognize the double quotes. Second and third mean Progra~1 does not exist. Did you type the double quotes from the keyboard or did you copy paste? It might be because they are non Ascii double quotes. Another workaround is to type `start ` before that.

Comment: What about: start "" "c:\program files\" as suggested by : https://superuser.com/questions/511486/how-to-start-open-a-file-folder-that-contains-space-in-its-name-through-command

Comment: It looks like the path is simply wrong. Run in command prompt window `cmd /?` and you can read on last help page about name completion used by typing just a few letters and hit key TAB to let Windows complete the rest. Also there are usually on system drive two program files folders and therefore `dir /AD /X %SystemDrive%\Progra*` must be executed to get the short path for a specific program files folder. And last the system drive is usually `C:` and not `H:`. As I replaced screen shot by text, I'm not sure if there is `0` or `O` in `R-3.4.0beta`. It should be `0`, but you typed perhaps `O`.

Comment: It is probably in bug in r.exe itself.  Consider running rterm.exe directly to bypass the bug.  Not too late to file a bug report btw.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue in Python:

1 `YT_DLP_LOCATION = "D:\\Programs\\yt dlp\\yt-dlp.exe"` 
2 `os.system(f"\"{YT_DLP_LOCATION}\" -o \"Downloaded songs/%(title)s - %(channel)s.%(ext)s\" -f bestaudio --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={link}")`
Print output is fine, manually works if I put the print output in CMD yet I still get the error that OP gets.

If I remove the -o option from yt-dlp (and the directory) somehow it works though. Not sure if it's a Python interpreter bug or something I didn't catch.

Answer (score 10):

**Short answer:** Use `& 'C:\path with spaces\app.exe'`

**Explanation:** Just type your path into powershell and use `TAB` for auto completion when you choose any directory containing spaces. Powershell will automatically insert *single quotes* `'bla bla'` and it will also put an `&` in front which is needed to treat the string as something that should be executed. Continue completing your path like usual.

Answer (score 5):

The way to do this - and I can't believe I'm just now figuring this out - is to use Windows short names generated for files with non-8dot3 names.  To get the path or program name in question, type `dir /x <path to program>`.  It will spit out something like `PROGRA~1` for `Program Files` folder.  Of course you have to do that directory by directory, and if you have multiple files/folders with spaces in the name, it's cumbersome. If you want the full path formatted with short names, you can do:

```
for %I in (*) do echo %~sI
```

For example, if the file I want to access is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\License Terms\License_msodbcsql_ENU.txt`, I could type:

```
for %I in ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\License Terms\License_msodbcsql_ENU.txt") do echo %~sI
```

And what I get back is the much easier `C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\CLIENT~1\ODBC\170\LICENS~1\LICENS~1.TXT`.

Annoying that you can't query the whole directory path without using a loop, but it is what it is.  Good for aliases.

There may be an easier way with powershell, but I'm pretty sure there isn't from the cmd prompt.

Answer (score 2):

you must be doing something wrong as the double quotes encapsulates the path to the executable including spaces.

To ensure you are doing it correctly, start typing the path to the command and use `TAB` after `F:\Program` until you see the correct path, in your case it will automatically do this

```
"F:\Program Files"
```

Use your arrow key to go back behind the end quotation and continue the path and use tab until you have reached.

```
"H:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0beta\bin\R.exe"
```

You can also try and issue it with `Start`

```
start "" "H:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0beta\bin\R.exe"
```

If Your cmd windows is open on the actual System drive where "Program Files" are located, you can run this instead of adding the drive letter as well:

```
".\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0beta\bin\R.exe"
```

Or add it to your environment variables with the path, then it should execute with just:

```
R.exe
```

Comment: This is literally broke in Windows 10.  Quoting the exeutable path, which absolutely exists, just returns file not found, instead of executing the executable.